# how to make org-mode section numbers start counting from 0 instead of 1?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

org-mode section numbers (when exported to html) by default starts count from 1, however it is traditional in computer science to start counting from zero. How to make org-mode section numbers start counting from 0 instead of 1?

Comment: Is this question about exporting to HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain lists are turned into HTML by the function `org-html-plain-list`, which calls `org-html-begin-plain-list`. `org-html-begin-plain-list` outputs the `<ol>` tag, and has a provision for outputting a `start` attribute as well, but `org-html-plain-list` doesn't use it. Interestingly, in the version of `org-mode` that I happen to have (which is 6 months old), there's a commented out section of code that looks like someone was thinking about implementing this:

```
(defun org-html-plain-list (plain-list contents info)
  "Transcode a PLAIN-LIST element from Org to HTML.
CONTENTS is the contents of the list.  INFO is a plist holding
contextual information."
  (let* (arg1 ;; (assoc :counter (org-element-map plain-list 'item
     (type (org-element-property :type plain-list)))
    (format "%s\n%s%s"
        (org-html-begin-plain-list type)
        contents (org-html-end-plain-list type))))
```

It looks like it would look for a `COUNTER` property nearby in the org file. Of course, that would still make you put something in for every single list you used, but it would be a start.

What you could do is use `add-advice` to override `org-html-begin-plain-list`, so that it always outputs a `start="0"` attribute on ordered lists. You might double-check what the latest version of `org-mode` does as well; perhaps they've improved it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack, but you can *mostly* get the numbering right by making the first section unnumbered.

In other words, this source file:

```
* Foo
  :PROPERTIES:
  :UNNUMBERED: t
  :END:
* Bar
* Baz
```

will result in this table of contents:

- Foo
- 1. Bar
- 2. Baz

It's not super ideal, but it's the best I've been able to do without hacking the org-mode source code.

Comment: I guess that as an additional hack you could simply change heading "* Foo" to be "* 0. Foo", and that would give the OP the zeroth list item he wanted.